# Selectric Jquery Plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm using selectric jquery plugin. My problem is: I have select. if user selects first option dynamically create new select with compatible options. if user selects second option dynamically create new select with compatible options. My english is very bad I'm sorry ;-)